# Python : Exit while loop when condition is met

Tags: python

Im trying to iterate over my list and calculate the diff between each element and the element following it. If the difference is greater than 0 ( or positive ) then increment `up` and decrease `down` by 1 ( if it is greater than 0 ). Similarly if difference is less than 0 then increment `down` and decrease `up` by 1 ( if greater than 0 ) . I want to exit out of the loop if either the `up` or `down` exceeds `limit` which is set to 3.

My code:

```
my_list = [13.04, 12.46, 13.1, 13.43, 13.76, 13.23, 12.15, 12.0, 11.55, 14.63]

up = 0
down = 0
limit = 3

while (up < limit) or (down < limit) :
    for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
        diff = my_list[i] - my_list[i+1]
        print (diff)
        if diff > 0:
            up +=1
            if down > 0:
                down -=1
        elif diff < 0:
            down +=1
            if up > 0:
                up -=1
```

Obviously this is not working since I keep getting caught up in an infinite loop and cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while condition is wrong. The loop keeps going while either `up` or `down` is below `limit`, so it will not stop even when `up=1000`, as long as `down<3`.
What you want is `while (up < limit) and (down < limit)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

do not use while , you can use if condition in last of for loop for break it :

```
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    diff = my_list[i] - my_list[i+1]
    #print (diff)
    if diff > 0:
        up +=1
        if down > 0:
            down -=1
    elif diff < 0:
        down +=1
        if up > 0:
            up -=1
    if (up > limit)or (down > limit) :print(up);print(down);break
```

Comment: While the main issue was changing `and` to `or` , this one makes sense too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your condition. You said you want to exit the program if either the `up` or `down` exceeds the `limit` which is set to 3. So the condition on the while loop needs to be set as `while up is less than limit AND down is also less than limit`, only then execute the body of the loop. Something like this.

```
while up < limit and down < limit:
```

or you can also use brackets (doesn't matter in this case)

```
while (up < limit) and (down < limit):
```

So the full program will be

```
my_list = [13.04, 12.46, 13.1, 13.43, 13.76, 13.23, 12.15, 12.0, 11.55, 14.63]

up = 0
down = 0
limit = 3

while up < limit and down < limit:
    for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
        diff = my_list[i] - my_list[i+1]
        print (diff)
        if diff > 0:
            up +=1
            if down > 0:
                down -=1
        elif diff < 0:
            down +=1
            if up > 0:
                up -=1
```